# KMM how to import the generated Greeting class in my current project?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I've added a KMM module in my Android Studio project.

My project builds successfully.

Now to test everything I'm trying to use the auto-created `Greeting` class in my main project, but autocompletion does not suggests the class.

Am I missing something? Do I need to add something to my gradle file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just created a new project with KMM Application Template then you might have already got the simple example where `Greeting` is already imported in the project.

Although if you are not able to import in any case then please check if you have added `shared` module in your dependencies of `App level build.gradle.kts` it looks like this :- `implementation(project(":shared"))`

and then you need to import is as
`your shared package name.Greeting` for example :- `import com.example.kmmsample.shared.Greeting` you can get your shared package name in `manifest file for shared module` it should be named as `androidMain\AndroidManifest.xml`

Now in iOS you can simply add it as `import shared` if you have already added it in your Framework.

Comment: `implementation(project(":shared"))` was missing in my module `gradle.build`. Working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help !!